# why window alert cannot work in any browser

Tags: asp.net

I have used `window.alert()` in my function previously it but now it cannot work properly.

```
showmessage("hi")
```

`ShowMessage()` method:

```
Protected Sub ShowMessage(ByVal stringMessageContent As String)
        If (stringMessageContent.Trim().Length > 0) Then

            stringMessageContent = stringMessageContent.Replace("\r\n", " ")
            stringMessageContent = stringMessageContent.Replace("'", "")
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(), "ClientScript", "<script language='JavaScript'>  window.alert('" + stringMessageContent + "');</script>")

        End If
End Sub
```

But the message does not show in any browser.

Comment: any console errors? which browser you are trying?

Comment: umm, what browser? on most browsers user can stop the page from generating any further pop up alert i believe..

Comment: I would not recommend using "give me" or "ASAP" here.